# При отправке json через ajax появляются лишние символы в Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, json, ajax

Не могу получить данные от пользователя.

###### JS:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/get-items',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')},
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'text': 'Hello',
        'url': $(location).attr("pathname"),
    },
    success: function(data){}
});
```

###### views.py:

```python
def get_all_items(request):

    body_unicode = request.body
    print(body_unicode)

    return JsonResponse({'status': True})
```

Получаю в консоле:

> b'text=Hello&url=%2Fabout-us%2F'

Если декодировать - `request.body.decode('UTF-8')` - получаю в консоле:

> text=Hello&url=%2Fabout-us%2F

При переводе в json формат `json.loads(body_unicode)` вылетает ошибка .

Как перевести полученные данные от клиента в json?

Comment: Если javascript отправляет данные в таком виде, то значит проблема в javascript и Django тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: И если уж вы зачем-то используете jQuery, то значит про него и ищите, как правильно отправить json https://stackoverflow.com/q/12693947

Comment: А вы, например, через postman пробовали отправлять данные? Такой же результат?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в отправке. Нужно было преобразовать в  json при отправке

```
data: JSON.stringify({
        'text': 'Hello',
        'url': $(location).attr("pathname"),
    }),
```